# Creating hot-spot in crime profiler?

Tags: mapinfo

I am trying to generate a hot-spot in crime profiler based on the total amounts of cost associated with a particular location.

I have multiple locations but I do not want a standard hot-spot showing the spread of the locations/incidents. Instead I want to use the sum of costs associated at the locations to generate the hot-spot.

In my data I have

- Location
- X and Y
- Sum of minutes
- Sum of costs
- Sum of incidents

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the ArcGIS spatial analyst extension, you could simply use the raster calculator ([Esri help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm)) to sum the minutes, costs, and incidents. Once you do that, you can visualize hot-spots. This assumes your layers are raster files - if not, please edit your question!

edit - see OPs comment below

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I do not have the Arcgis add on. I am using crimeprofiler in mapinfo and would like to create a hotspot based on the spread of costs. My data is perhaps confusing this. I have an excel pivot table of locations, incident count for each location and combined costs for each location. I have mapped these locations but now I want to create a hotspot based on the values for combined cost or combined incident count and not on the actual spread of locations. This is what is happening automatically. I hope this clarifies this and again thanks for the help here. Best wishes. James

Comment: OK. I removed the 'spatial analyst' tag that was on your question. I am not familiar with MapInfo, so I won't be much help!